# What is causing sr.lock on tables after looping?

Tags: arcpy, lock

The following code puts an sr.lock on each table in my List.   What’s causing my tables to lock up?

I understand my script is reading or opening my tables temporarily to perform the “MakeRouteEventLayer_lr” Geoprocessing but since I’m not necessarily inserting a cursor I should not have to delete references to a table right?

As a result of my tables locking up while running the “MakeRouteEventLayer_lr()”,  I am not able to run the second Geoprocessing tool “arcpy.AddXY_management()”.

Currently, in order to accomplish my task I have to run each of the Geoprocessing as a standalone process and even then the tables are locked once they finish processing.

I would greatly appreciate it if someone can help me isolate this problem. By the way my source data is in a file geodatabase. I've ran the code below in pythonWin and ArcMap with the same results.

```
# First Geoprocessing

Table_List = arcpy.ListTables()
for t_list in Table_List:
    arcpy.MakeRouteEventLayer_lr(PODS_ROUTEM, "ROUTE_CODE", t_list, "Route_Code POINT measure", t_list+'_EVENT', "", "NO_ERROR_FIELD", "NO_ANGLE_FIELD", "NORMAL", "ANGLE", "LEFT", "POINT")
    arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(t_list+'_EVENT',t_list+'_EVENT')

# Second geoprocessing    

fc_list = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()
for fc in fc_list:     
    arcpy.AddXY_management(fc)
    arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(fc,fc)
```

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to copy features back to themselves.  See the documentation on [CopyFeatures_management](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//001700000035000000) for correct usage.  Your in features should be different to your output feature class.  That is most likely why you are getting a lock.

In the first Geoprocessing, change the output feature class to something else.  Do the same to the second Geoprocessing.